Query that will find users who post THE SAME SET of marks as user2
I have a table ORDERS which consists of columns "user", "mark" and "mark_cnt".
And I need to write such an sql query that will output me those users which have the same set of marks as user2. He has one m1, two m2 and one m4. So, basically, it means that this set must fully intersect with other users marks.
U1 has: m1, m2, m2, m3, m4, m4, m4
U2 has: m1, m2, m2, m4
U3 has: m1, m2, m2, m2, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m4, m4, m4, m5
U4 has: m1, m2, m4
I tried to use this code:
select user
from orders
where mark in  (
               select mark from orders where user='u2'
               )
group by user
having count(mark) = (select count(mark) from order where user='u2')


The correct answer must be U1 and U3

This is classic Relational Division With Remainder, with the slight tweak that mark_cnt matches if it is greater than or equal to the original set's row.
There are many solutions. The most efficient is usually to use a having to compare the count of matches.
select others.`user`
from orders as original
join orders as others
  on others.mark = original.mark
 and others.mark_cnt >= original.mark_cnt
 and others.`user` <> original.`user`
where original.`user` = 'U2'
group by
  others.`user`
having
  count(*) = (select count(*) from orders as o where o.`user` = 'U2');

db<>fiddle
Note that the other answer does not return correct results in the case where there is at least one row in the original set which doesn't match anywhere.

I've created a DBFiddle with the data from the question and a best-effort solution.

The way I'm reading the question is that for user A to match user B, user A's multiset of marks must be a subset of user B's multiset. The pair U1 & U3 fullfils this condition but so do others. For example, the pair U4 & U1.
A literal interpretation would be that user A's multiset has to exactly equal user B's multiset, but that would produce no answers. Relaxing that condition to exclude elements not contained at all in one of the multisets would produce U1 & U2 as the answer, which is different from the suggested correct answer.
Since the question contradicts the intended answer, this is a "best-effort" answer and you should please clarify the actual condition for including the row. For example, you could explain why U1 & U3 is the only answer or what other pairs are in the answer. I don't meet the reputation requirement to ask in a comment :P

Here is the explanation of the query:

Start with just the obvious: we want to SELECT user names from the orders table:

select "user" from orders


Let's match each order with every other order containing for the same mark. Use a join with a condition and add table aliases to disambiguate:

select
  o1."user"
from
  orders o1
inner join
  orders o2
  on o1.mark = o2.mark


Filter out pairs of rows from the same user:

select
  o1."user"
from
  orders o1
inner join
  orders o2
  on (
    o1."user" != o2."user" and
    o1.mark = o2.mark
  )


Now let's see if the orders are a subset by comparing the counts. We will include the second username now as well:

select
  o1."user",
  o2."user",
  o2.mark_cnt >= o1.mark_cnt
    as "is_subset"
from
  orders o1
inner join
  orders o2
  on (
    o1."user" != o2."user" and
    o1.mark = o2.mark
  )


Now we want to keep only statements for the pairs of users where ALL the rows are is_subset. Use a GROUP BY with an aggregation function to calculate the logical AND of all the rows for each pair:

select
  o1."user",
  o2."user"
from
  orders o1
inner join
  orders o2
  on (
    o1."user" != o2."user" and
    o1.mark = o2.mark
  )
group by
  o1."user", o2."user"
having
  bool_and(
    o2.mark_cnt >= o1.mark_cnt
  )


Finally, note that the INNER JOIN variant will remove any orders which do not have an equivalent for user 2. Instead, we want to fail the test as it would mean that for one of the marks there is no match. We will use a LEFT JOIN to "prioritize" the rows from user 1. Since we switch to an outer join, we will also need need to deal with o2.mark_cnt possibly being NULL using a coalesce:

select
    o1."user",
    o2."user"
from
    orders o1
left join
    orders o2
    on (
        o1."user" != o2."user" and
        o2.mark = o1.mark
    )
group by
    o1."user", o2."user"
having
    bool_and(
        coalesce(o2.mark_cnt, 0) >= o1.mark_cnt
    )


Thank you for your answer.
Comment:
U2 has the following set of "marks" : m1, m2, m2, m4
The task is to 'iterate' through other users and check whether they have "m1" and "m2" and "m2" and "m4" simultaneously.
For example, if we loop through user1
U1 has: m1, m2, m2, m3, m4, m4, m4,
we can see that he also has m1, m2,m2, m4 in his list.
If we go through user3:
U3 has: m1, m2, m2, m2, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m3, m4,...we can see that he also has this "set" in his list.
If we iterate through user4
U4 has: m1, m2, m4,
we can see that he doesn't have m1, m2,m2, m4 in his list.

does not return correct results if there is any row in the source set which does not have any match anywhere else. The correct result should be empty for U2 https://dbfiddle.uk/3nxknKbQ

Try this way:
WITH
    'u2' AS user_id,
    /* Emulate the test dataset. */
    order AS
    (
        SELECT
            user,
            arrayJoin(marks) AS mark
        FROM VALUES(
            'user String, marks Array(String)', 
            ('u1', ['m1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm4', 'm4']), 
            ('u2', ['m1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm4']), 
            ('u3', ['m1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm4', 'm4', 'm4', 'm5']), 
            ('u4', ['m1', 'm2', 'm4']))
    ),
    base_user AS
    (
        SELECT groupArray((mark, count))
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                mark,
                count() AS count
            FROM order
            WHERE user = user_id
            GROUP BY mark
        )
        LIMIT 1
    )
SELECT
    user,
    CAST((groupArray(mark), groupArray(count)), 'Map(String, UInt64)') AS map
FROM
(
    SELECT
        user,
        mark,
        count() AS count
    FROM order
    WHERE (mark IN (
        SELECT mark
        FROM order
        WHERE user = user_id
    )) AND (user != user_id)
    GROUP BY
        user,
        mark
)
GROUP BY user
HAVING arrayAll(x -> map[x.1] >= x.2, (
    SELECT *
    FROM base_user
))

/*
┌─user─┬─map────────────────────┐
│ u3   │ {'m1':1,'m4':3,'m2':3} │
│ u1   │ {'m1':1,'m4':3,'m2':2} │
└──────┴────────────────────────┘
*/

